# Agregar un archivo como variable para editar un formulario

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Tengo el siguiente código para crear y para actualizar datos. Para crear no hay problema, pero cuando quiero actualizar al querer cargar la información que actualmente tiene el elemento  en el `Form::file`, la parte de `$product->imagen` tiene la ruta de donde está almacenada la imagen, en ese lugar debería ir un archivo. ¿Cómo hacer para cargar ahí el archivo de esa ruta? Estoy utilizando Laravel Collective.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('descripcion') }}
    {{ Form::text('descripcion', $product->descripcion, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('descripcion') ? ' is-invalid' : ''),'placeholder' => 'Descripcion']) }}
    {!! $errors->first('descripcion', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('imagen') }}
    {{ Form::file('imagen', $product->imagen, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('imagen') ? ' is-invalid' : ''),'placeholder' => 'Imagen']) }}
    {!! $errors->first('imagen', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
</div>
...
```

Comment: La única manera de asignar valor a un input type file, es que el usuario seleccione un archivo.

Comment: Hay un complemento HTML que hace eso, sin tener que generar la echo Form::file('image'); en la documentacion estan los detalles https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#file-input